# Referencing variables across `copy` declarations in Azure ARM templates

Tags: .net, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm creating an Azure ARM template. I'm using the `copy` declaration to avoiding repeating my code; however, I've found that this often leads to repetition itself. Consider the following example from [ARM Lab 6](https://azurecitadel.com/automation/arm/lab6/#copy-objects):

```
  "variables": {
    "hubID": "[if(parameters('peer'), resourceId(parameters('hub').resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('hub').vnet.name), '')]",
    "spokeID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('spoke').vnet.name)]",
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "subnets",
            "count": "[length(parameters('spoke').subnets)]",
            "input": {
              "name": "[parameters('spoke').subnets[copyIndex('subnets')].name]",
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('spoke').subnets[copyIndex('subnets')].addressPrefix]",
              "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('spoke').vnet.name), '/subnets/', parameters('spoke').subnets[copyIndex('subnets')].name)]"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

The `parameters('spoke').subnets[copyIndex('subnets')]` expression is repeated several times. Is there a way of assigning the result of this `copy`-indexed expression to a variable that could then be referenced within the `copy` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so, you could, in theory create a variable with the list of those id's and use `copyIndex()` to access those in several other copy variables, but you'd still have to declare that first variable in a similar fashion.

Technically you can write a function that would accept `copyIndex()` value as input and retrieve that specific instance from the `parameters('spoke').subnets` array, but given you need both `name` and `addressPrefix` function would also need to accept which parameter to return (or it would return an object and you'd need to access that object properties). I'm not sure ARM Template function can return an object, I never really worked with functions in ARM Templates because they are pretty much useless.